# How to use IF Else in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to use If Else in Sql Server Query.

Lets Consider the Table below

```
Product   Kg    Qty    Rate
----------------------------
Mango      1      3      70
Orange     0      2      80
Apple      3      4      90
```

I need to sum Kg, qty and rate(kg*Qty*rate) as Total. But when kg is 0 i need to sum only qty*rate.

I need a output like,

```
Product   Kg    Qty    Rate   Total
-----------------------------------
Mango      1      3      70    210
Orange     0      2      80    160
Apple      3      4      90    1080
```

How can I use If Else here???

Comment: use case when clause in sql server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (CASE Kg WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE Kg END) * Qty * Rate  AS Total
FROM Products
```

Please have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58befa/4/0).

Answer (score 2):

you can use this query

```
select *, case when kg > 0 
 then  kg + qty + rate 
  else
    qty + rate 
    end as "total" 
from table3
```

look at attached image

[image]